# Scrape website to only show populated categories

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am in the process of scraping a website and it pulls the contents of the page, but there are categories with headers that are technically empty, but it still shows the header. I would like to only see categories with events in them. Ideally I could even have the components of each transactions so I can choose which elements I want displayed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

print('Scraping NH Dept of Banking...')
print()

NHurl = 'https://www.nh.gov/banking/corporate-activities/index.htm'
NHr = requests.get(NHurl, headers = headers)

NHsoup = BeautifulSoup(NHr.text, 'html.parser')

NHlist = []

for events in NHsoup.findAll('tr')[2:]:
    print(events.text)
    NHlist.append(events.text)
print(' '.join(NHlist))
```

Like I said, this works to get all of the information, but there are a lot of headers/empty space that doesn't need to be pulled. For example, at the time I'm writing this the 'acquisitions', 'conversions', and 'change in control' are empty, but the headers still come in and there's are relatively large blank space after the headers. I feel like a I need some sort of loop to go through each header ('td') and then get it's contents ('tr') but I'm just not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group elements and then filter out empty rows:

```
import requests
from itertools import groupby
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

print('Scraping NH Dept of Banking...')
print()

NHurl = 'https://www.nh.gov/banking/corporate-activities/index.htm'
NHr = requests.get(NHurl, headers = headers)

NHsoup = BeautifulSoup(NHr.text, 'html.parser')

NHlist = []
for _, g in groupby(NHsoup.select('tr'), lambda k, d={'g':0}: (d.update(g=d['g']+1), d['g']) if k.select('th') else (None, d['g'])):
    s = [tag.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for tag in g]
    if any(i == '' for i in s):
        continue
    NHlist.append(s)

# This is just pretty printing, all the data are already in NHlist:
l = max(map(len,(j for i in NHlist for j in i))) + 5
for item in NHlist:
    print('{: <4} {}'.format(' ', item[0]))
    print('-' * l)
    for i, ev in enumerate(item[1:], 1):
        print('{: <4} {}'.format(i, ev))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Scraping NH Dept of Banking...

     New Bank
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    12/11/18 The Millyard Bank

     Interstate Bank Combination
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    01/16/19 Optima Bank & Trust Company with and into Cambridge Trust Company Portsmouth, NH 03/29/19

     Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorporation; Business or Capital Plan
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    11/26/18 John Hancock Trust Company Boston, MA 01/14/19
2    12/04/18 Franklin Savings Bank Franklin, NH 01/28/19
3    12/12/18 MFS Heritage Trust Company Boston, MA 01/28/19
4    02/25/19 Ankura Trust Company, LLC Fairfield, CT 03/22/19
5    4/25/19 Woodsville Guaranty Savings Bank Woodsville, NH 06/04/19
6    5/10/19 AB Trust Company New York, NY 06/04/19

     Reduction in Capital
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    03/07/19 Primary Bank Bedford, NH 04/10/19

     Amendment to Bylaws
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    12/10/18 Northeast Credit Union Porstmouth, NH 02/25/19
2    2/25/19 Members First Credit Union Manchester, NH 04/05/19
3    4/24/19 St. Mary's Bank Manchester, NH 05/30/19
4    6/28/19 Bellwether Community Credit Union

     Interstate Branch Office
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    01/23/19 Newburyport Five Cents Savings Bank 141 Portsmouth Ave Exeter, NH 02/01/19
2    03/08/19 One Credit Union Newport, NH 03/29/19
3    03/01/19 JPMorgan Chase Bank, NA Nashua, NH 04/04/19
4    03/26/19 Mascoma Bank Lebanon, NH 04/09/19
5    04/24/19 Newburyport Five Cents Savings Bank 321 Lafayette Rd Hampton NH 05/08/19
6    07/10/19 Mascoma Bank 242-244 North Winooski Avenue Burlington VT 07/18/19
7    07/10/19 Mascoma Bank 431 Pine Street Burlington VT 07/18/19

     Interstate Branch Office Closure
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    02/15/19 The Provident Bank 321 Lafayette Rd Hampton, NH 02/25/19

     New Branch Office
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    12/07/18 Bank of New Hampshire 16-18 South Main Street Concord NH 01/02/19
2    3/4/19 Triangle Credit Union 360 Daniel Webster Highway, Merrimack, NH 03/11/19
3    04/03/19 Bellwether Community Credit Union 425-453 Commercial Street Manchester, NH 04/17/19
4    06/11/19 Primary Bank 23 Crystal Avenue Derry NH 06/11/19

     Branch Office Closure
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    5/15/19 Northeast Credit Union Merrimack, NH 05/21/19

     New Loan Production Office
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    04/08/19 Community National Bank 367 Route 120, Unit B-5 Lebanon, NH
            03766-1430 04/15/19

     Loan Production Office Closure
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    07/22/19 The Provident Bank 20 Trafalgar Square, Suite 447 Nashua NH  03063 07/31/19

     Trade Name Requests
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    04/16/19 John Hancock Trust Company To use trade name "Manulife Investment Management Trust Company" 04/24/19

     New Trust Company
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    02/19/19 Janney Trust Co., LLC
2    02/25/19 Darwin Trust Company of New Hampshire, LLC
3    07/15/`9 Harbor Trust Company

     Dissolution of Trust Company
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    09/19/17 Cambridge Associates Fiduciary Trust, LLC Boston, MA 02/05/19

     Trust Office Closure
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    5/10/19 Charter Trust Company Rochester, NH 05/20/19

     New Trust Office
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    02/25/19 Ankura Trust Company, LLC 140 Sherman Street, 4th Floor Fairfield, CT 06824 03/22/19

     Relocation of Trust Office
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    01/23/19 Geode Capital Management Trust Company, LLC Relocate from: One Post Office Square, 20th Floor, Boston MA To: 100 Summer Street, 12th Flr, Boston, MA 02/01/19
2    03/15/19 Drivetrain Trust Company LLC Relocate from: 630 3rd Avenue, 21st Flr New York, NY 10017 To: 410 Park Avenue, Suite 900 New York, NY 10022 03/29/19
3    04/14/19 Boston Partners Trust Company Relocate from: 909 Third Avenue New York, NY 10022 To: One Grand Central Place 60 East 42nd Street, Ste 1550 New York, NY 10165 04/23/19
```

Comment: nice solution here!

Answer (score 1):

You could test which rows contain all '\xa0' (appear blank) and exclude. I append to list and convert to pandas dataframe but you could just print the row direct.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.nh.gov/banking/corporate-activities/index.htm')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
results = []

for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    row = [i.text for i in tr.select('th,td')]
    if row.count('\xa0') != len(row):
        results.append(row)

pd.set_option('display.width', 100)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})   
df.columns = df.iloc[0] 
df = df[1:]
df.fillna(value='', inplace=True)
print(df.head(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is how you want it, and there is probably a more elegant way, but I basically did was

1. Pandas to get the table
2. Pandas automatically assigns columns, so moved column to first row
3. Found were rows are all nulls
4. Dropped rows with all nulls and the previous row (it's sub header)

   import pandas as pd

   print('Scraping NH Dept of Banking...')
   print()

   NHurl = 'https://www.nh.gov/banking/corporate-activities/index.htm'

   df = pd.read_html(NHurl)[0]
   top_row = pd.DataFrame([df.columns], index=[-1])
   df.columns = top_row.columns
   df = df.append(top_row, sort=True).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

   null_rows = df[df.isnull().values.all(axis=1)].index.tolist()

   drop_hdr_rows = [x - 1 for x in null_rows ]
   drop_rows = drop_hdr_rows + null_rows

   new_df = df[~df.index.isin(drop_rows)]

**Output:**

```
print (new_df.to_string())
                                                    0                                                  1                                                  2                                                  3
2                                            New Bank                                           New Bank                                           New Bank                                           New Bank
3                                            12/11/18                                  The Millyard Bank                                                NaN                                                NaN
4                         Interstate Bank Combination                        Interstate Bank Combination                        Interstate Bank Combination                        Interstate Bank Combination
5                                            01/16/19  Optima Bank & Trust Company with and into Camb...                                     Portsmouth, NH                                           03/29/19
12  Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorpor...  Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorpor...  Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorpor...  Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorpor...
13                                           11/26/18                         John Hancock Trust Company                                         Boston, MA                                           01/14/19
14                                           12/04/18                              Franklin Savings Bank                                       Franklin, NH                                           01/28/19
15                                           12/12/18                         MFS Heritage Trust Company                                         Boston, MA                                           01/28/19
16                                           02/25/19                          Ankura Trust Company, LLC                                      Fairfield, CT                                           03/22/19
17                                            4/25/19                   Woodsville Guaranty Savings Bank                                     Woodsville, NH                                           06/04/19
18                                            5/10/19                                   AB Trust Company                                       New York, NY                                           06/04/19
19                               Reduction in Capital                               Reduction in Capital                               Reduction in Capital                               Reduction in Capital
20                                           03/07/19                                       Primary Bank                                        Bedford, NH                                           04/10/19
21                                Amendment to Bylaws                                Amendment to Bylaws                                Amendment to Bylaws                                Amendment to Bylaws
22                                           12/10/18                             Northeast Credit Union                                     Porstmouth, NH                                           02/25/19
23                                            2/25/19                         Members First Credit Union                                     Manchester, NH                                           04/05/19
24                                            4/24/19                                    St. Mary's Bank                                     Manchester, NH                                           05/30/19
25                                            6/28/19                  Bellwether Community Credit Union                                                NaN                                                NaN
26                           Interstate Branch Office                           Interstate Branch Office                           Interstate Branch Office                           Interstate Branch Office
27                                           01/23/19                Newburyport Five Cents Savings Bank                     141 Portsmouth Ave  Exeter, NH                                           02/01/19
28                                           03/08/19                                   One Credit Union                                        Newport, NH                                           03/29/19
29                                           03/01/19                            JPMorgan Chase Bank, NA                                         Nashua, NH                                           04/04/19
30                                           03/26/19                                       Mascoma Bank                                        Lebanon, NH                                           04/09/19
31                                           04/24/19                Newburyport Five Cents Savings Bank                       321 Lafayette Rd  Hampton NH                                           05/08/19
32                                           07/10/19                                       Mascoma Bank       242-244 North Winooski Avenue  Burlington VT                                           07/18/19
33                                           07/10/19                                       Mascoma Bank                     431 Pine Street  Burlington VT                                           07/18/19
34                   Interstate Branch Office Closure                   Interstate Branch Office Closure                   Interstate Branch Office Closure                   Interstate Branch Office Closure
35                                           02/15/19                                 The Provident Bank                      321 Lafayette Rd  Hampton, NH                                           02/25/19
36                                  New Branch Office                                  New Branch Office                                  New Branch Office                                  New Branch Office
37                                           12/07/18                              Bank of New Hampshire                16-18 South Main Street  Concord NH                                           01/02/19
38                                             3/4/19                              Triangle Credit Union         360 Daniel Webster Highway,  Merrimack, NH                                           03/11/19
39                                           04/03/19                  Bellwether Community Credit Union          425-453 Commercial Street  Manchester, NH                                           04/17/19
40                                           06/11/19                                       Primary Bank                        23 Crystal Avenue  Derry NH                                           06/11/19
41                              Branch Office Closure                              Branch Office Closure                              Branch Office Closure                              Branch Office Closure
42                                            5/15/19                             Northeast Credit Union                                      Merrimack, NH                                           05/21/19
43                         New Loan Production Office                         New Loan Production Office                         New Loan Production Office                         New Loan Production Office
44                                           04/08/19                            Community National Bank   367 Route 120, Unit B-5  Lebanon, NH  03766-1430                                           04/15/19
45                     Loan Production Office Closure                     Loan Production Office Closure                     Loan Production Office Closure                     Loan Production Office Closure
46                                           07/22/19                                 The Provident Bank    20 Trafalgar Square, Suite 447  Nashua NH 03063                                           07/31/19
51                                Trade Name Requests                                Trade Name Requests                                Trade Name Requests                                Trade Name Requests
52                                           04/16/19                         John Hancock Trust Company  To use trade name "Manulife Investment Managem...                                           04/24/19
53                                  New Trust Company                                  New Trust Company                                  New Trust Company                                  New Trust Company
54                                           02/19/19                              Janney Trust Co., LLC                                                NaN                                                NaN
55                                           02/25/19         Darwin Trust Company of New Hampshire, LLC                                                NaN                                                NaN
56                                           07/15/`9                               Harbor Trust Company                                                NaN                                                NaN
57                       Dissolution of Trust Company                       Dissolution of Trust Company                       Dissolution of Trust Company                       Dissolution of Trust Company
58                                           09/19/17          Cambridge Associates Fiduciary Trust, LLC                                         Boston, MA                                           02/05/19
59                               Trust Office Closure                               Trust Office Closure                               Trust Office Closure                               Trust Office Closure
60                                            5/10/19                              Charter Trust Company                                      Rochester, NH                                           05/20/19
61                                   New Trust Office                                   New Trust Office                                   New Trust Office                                   New Trust Office
62                                           02/25/19                          Ankura Trust Company, LLC  140 Sherman Street, 4th Floor  Fairfield, CT 0...                                           03/22/19
63                         Relocation of Trust Office                         Relocation of Trust Office                         Relocation of Trust Office                         Relocation of Trust Office
64                                           01/23/19        Geode Capital Management Trust Company, LLC  Relocate from: One Post Office Square, 20th Fl...                                           02/01/19
65                                           03/15/19                       Drivetrain Trust Company LLC  Relocate from: 630 3rd Avenue, 21st Flr  New Y...                                           03/29/19
66                                           04/14/19                      Boston Partners Trust Company  Relocate from: 909 Third Avenue  New York, NY ...                                           04/23/19
```